# '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'. Beginner and do not know what to do

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that sees if two dates match out of a list of 30 dates ranging from 1 to 365
While trying to test the program, I keep encountering the error "'<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'" and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here is my program so far:

```
import random

MaxInList = 30

def createDayNumberList( howMany = MaxInList ):

      dayNumbers = []
      for counter in range( howMany ):
            nextDayNumber = random.randint( 1, 365 )
            dayNumbers.append( nextDayNumber )
      return dayNumbers

def determineDate( dayNumber = 1 ):

      months = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
      name = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
              "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ] 
      endOfMonth = 0
      daysSoFar = 0
      for month in range( len( months ) ):
            endOfMonth += months[month]
            if dayNumber <= endOfMonth:
                  date = name[month]
                  date += " " + str( dayNumber - daysSoFar )
                  return date
            daysSoFar = endOfMonth
      return "Bad date!"

def main ():

    listsToGenerate = 10
    for n in range( listsToGenerate ):
        determineDate( createDayNumberList () )
        print("")

main ()
```

Any sort of help/feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `createDayNumberList ()` returns a list, which sets `dayNumber` to a list. Then you do `dayNumber <= endOfMonth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is in your `main()` function:

```
def main ():

    listsToGenerate = 10
    for n in range( listsToGenerate ):
        determineDate( createDayNumberList() ) ## 
        print("")
```

`createDayNumberList()` returns a `List` object. This is passed to `determineDate()` and then the comparison is made:

`if dayNumber <= endOfMonth` ,
where `dayNumber` is a List object and `endOfMonth` is an `INT`. Hence, the error.

In my understanding, since your `createDayNumberList()` always returns just 1 value, you can store it in a variable rather than storing it in a list.

Something like:

```
def createDayNumberList( howMany = MaxInList ):
    dayNumbers = []
    for counter in range( howMany ):
        nextDayNumber = random.randint( 1, 365 )
        #dayNumbers.append( nextDayNumber )
      return nextDayNumber
```

Now, this function also returns an `int`. So, the comparison in  `determineDate()` will always be correct.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. That's one of the many issues I'm having fixed! I'm not sure how I should proceed but thank you again for the help!